# wso2 governance registry or / and svn repository with an esb cluster?

Tags: svn, cluster-computing, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

wso2 governance registry is highly recommanded to share esb artifacts, so our sequences and endpoints are registred on this one. API and proxy-services are stored in each esb instance.
But, we need to use an esb cluster (1 manager/2 worker), and the synchronization of esb artifacts is based on svn repository=> does it mean that:
-api and proxy-services synchronization in esb cluster will be managed on svn repository
-sequences and endpoints are managed on governance registry, but it seems that when I update a sequence in registry, worker nodes and manager node use old version (I use ATOM protocol)
So, what are best practices to synchronize esb artifacts in a wso2 esb cluster?
cheers

Answer (score 0):

When we create a cluster we use svn as the Deployment Synchronizer. The artifacts are kept at the svn location which configured in the /repository/conf/carbon.xml. Follow [1] for more information and the cluster implementation.

[1] http://jagathsa.blogspot.com/2015/06/creating-esb-cluster-with-nginx-lb.html

Hope this Helps !!